# XML Parsing in C# .net 4

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I have following xml How can I read xml to get list of Sura nodes like this

---

```
var Suras = XMLNodes **//how to use xpath to load xmlnodes of sura**

foreach (var sura in suras)
{
    var ayas =  sura. **//how to use xpath to load xmlnodes of aya for this sura node**
}
```

---

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<quran>
  <sura index="1" name="الفاتحة">
    <aya index="1" text="In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful."/>
    <aya index="2" text="[All] praise is [due] to Allah, Lord of the worlds -"/>
  </sura>
  <sura index="114" name="الناس">
    <aya index="1" text="Say, &quot;I seek refuge in the Lord of mankind,"/>
    <aya index="2" text="The Sovereign of mankind."/>
    <aya index="3" text="The God of mankind,"/>
    <aya index="4" text="From the evil of the retreating whisperer -"/>
    <aya index="5" text="Who whispers [evil] into the breasts of mankind -"/>
    <aya index="6" text="From among the jinn and mankind.&quot;"/>
  </sura>
</quran>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you *particularly* want to use XPath? I'd just use LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var suras = doc.Root.Elements("sura");
foreach (var sura in suras)
{
    var ayas = suras.Elements("aya");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes want to use without LINQ to XML. So it will work on .net 4 & 2 both.